# HTML Marquee text on my site moves at a weird speed but when it's viewed in Chrome, it's perfectly fine?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>namename</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="mainbanner">
        <h4><marquee loop="100">hello i'm moving<img src="emoticon.png" alt="sarang" height="30" width="30"></h4></marquee>
        <h1>aaa®</h1>

       <nav id="primary_nav_wrap"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">page1</a></li> |
            <li><a href="">page2</a></li> |
            <li><a href="">page3</a></li> |
            <li><a href="">page4</a></li> | 
            <li><a href="">page5</a></li> |
            <li><a href="">page6</a></li> |
            <li><a href="">page 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>


    <div id="time">
    </div>

     <div class="board">

    </div>

    <div class="signup">
        <button>aaa login</button>
    </div>

    <div class="gaeshi">
        <h4>board</h4>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">board 1</a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">board 2</a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">board 3</a>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">board 4</a>
    </div>

<div class="music">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="slow" scrollamount="5"><h3>song playing</marquee></h3>
    <audio controls style="width: 200px;" autoplay="autoplay" />
        <source src="todaysong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

    <div class="search">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button>Search</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>


    <!--FOOTER --> 
    <div id="footer">
   <p class="copyright">© 2016 aaa. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I open the HTML file on Chrome, everything looks fine and normal with everything the way I want it to be. However, when I open it on Safari, the marquee text on the top moving right to left appears to be weird and makes me dizzy when  look at it and the margin/alignment is slightly off. Is there a way I can fix this issue? Can't seem to figure out what the problem may be. It just looks strange and different on Safari.

Answer (score 3):

`marquee` is an obsolete feature. It shouldn't be used because it does not have particularly strong cross-browser compatibility.

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

The `truespeed` attribute in particular has no support in either Opera or Safari.

Comment: In fact, `<marquee>` has never been part of any HTML specification ever. Only its behavior is defined in HTML5 so it can be obsoleted (for whatever strange reason that is).

Answer (score 0):

> This  tag is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Why don't you create a marquee with pure CSS using keyframes, like that:

http://codepen.io/gabrielgodoy/pen/mEdZbr

```
@keyframes scroll{
  0% {
   left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -800px;
  }
}
```

And the on the element that you want to move:

```
animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
```