# Scrolling text marquee not working in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scroll marquee. It works perfect in Chrome but not in IE and Edge

The marquee does not have any hardcoded text to display, as the text is selected rom a MySQL database. The select query and php variable is done correctly because it works in Chrome

**AJAX**

```
function scrollhandler() {
   $.getJSON("check_time_scroll.php", function(update) {
    if (update.count===true) {
    $("#scrolltext").load('unifoscrolltext.php');
    } 
});
}
setInterval(scrollhandler, 10000);
</script>
```

```js
function calcSpeed(speed) {
  // Time = Distance/Speed
  var spanSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.marquee span'),
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < spanSelector.length; i++) {
    var spanLength = spanSelector[i].offsetWidth,
        timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
    spanSelector[i].style.animation = "marquee linear infinite " + timeTaken + "s";
  }
}
calcSpeed(42);
```

```css
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  font: 50px Verdana;
  display: inline-block;
}
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}
/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(10%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
/* Make it pretty */
.scroll {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  font: 50px Verdana;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  left: 0px;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span id="scrolltext">Hello world</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Marquee text on my site moves at a weird speed but when it's viewed in Chrome, it's perfectly fine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535020/html-marquee-text-on-my-site-moves-at-a-weird-speed-but-when-its-viewed-in-chro)

Comment: @RichardHamilton That question uses a `<marquee>`. This one uses CSS animation.

Comment: It works for me on IE.

Comment: @RichardHamilton. Wrong

Comment: I answered that question before, so I thought it seemed familiar. My point was that `marquee` is obsolete and shouldn't be used in either HTML or CSS

Comment: @Oriol. Thanks. I see your snippet and it works in my IE and Edge as well. Now I am really confused. Using my php variable I works in Chrome but not IE and Edge. When its hardcoded text like your snippet, it works.

Comment: The browser never sees the PHP code. It can't know if you hardcoded the text or retrieved it from somewhere. So PHP is completely unrelated.

Comment: @Oriol. Using a time check script, I check the database for new cntent in the DB. If the is new content it will update the `<div>`. Tx. his is done via Ajax. Please see my Edit in the question. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: @Wienievra what is 'update' and where is it defined/passed from (its in your AJAX - passed into your function)? are you returning the  value from the php script (there is no sign of it in the posted code) make sure that you are passing that value to the function correctly.